# Count number of children recursively in Javascript/Typescript/ES6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a recursive method that would give me the count of all items with children.

I am currently just looking three levels deep and incrementing a counter when I find that an item has children.

However I want to be able to recursively check until no children are present in the array.

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'parent',
        children: [
            {
                id: 12,
                name: 'firstChild',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 22,
                        name: 'firstGrandChild',
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 32,
                                name: 'GreatGrandChild',
                                children: []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'secondRowFirstChild',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 13,
                        name: 'secondRowGrandChild',
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'thirdRowFirstChild',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 14,
                        name: 'thirdRowGrandChild',
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]


// Here is the procedural code that I want to convert

getExpandableRowCount(items: TableRow[]): number {
    let count = 0

    items.map(item => {
        if (item.children && item.children.length) {
            count++;
            item.children.map(subItem => {
                if (subItem.children && subItem.children.length) {
                    count++;
                    subItem.children.map(subSubItem => {
                        if (subSubItem.children && subSubItem.children.length) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    });

  return count;
}
```

I expect the count to be 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()`, and if an item has `children` with a length greater than 0, add 1, call `count` on them, and add to the total:

```js
const count = arr => arr.reduce((r, { children = [] }) => 
  children.length ? r + 1 + count(children) : r
, 0)

const data = [{"id":2,"name":"parent","children":[{"id":12,"name":"firstChild","children":[{"id":22,"name":"firstGrandChild","children":[{"id":32,"name":"GreatGrandChild","children":[]}]}]},{"id":3,"name":"secondRowFirstChild","children":[{"id":13,"name":"secondRowGrandChild","children":[]}]},{"id":4,"name":"thirdRowFirstChild","children":[{"id":14,"name":"thirdRowGrandChild","children":[]}]}]}]

const result = count(data)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!